# Getting BSOD During Gaming - Win10/NVidia/AMD

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

### The Problem

So a few months ago I built a gaming PC and up until a couple of weeks ago it's been running fine. Now it will randomly blue screen while playing games. Sometimes within minutes, sometimes after an hour, but it will always happen. I don't typically ask for help with this kind of stuff since I've been building PCs for so long, but I'm kind of at a loss on this one. Other than a dead graphics card, I can't figure out what's wrong with it. So before I go through the trouble of warrantying the graphics card, I thought I'd ask some other professionals and get a second opinion.

### PC Info

**Hardware**:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
- GPU: Gigabyte RTX 4070ti Aero OC
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro (16gb x 4)
- MoBo: Gigabyte X570S Aorus Master
- PSU: Corsair HX1000

**OS**: Fresh install of Windows 10, all Windows updates applied. Windows and all system drivers/utilities are installed on the primary NVME drive (C:). All applications/games are stored on a secondary SSD (F:).

**Graphics Drivers**: DDU Run to remove default Windows installation of NVidia Drivers. Latest stand-alone driver from NVidia installed (no GeForce Experience).

### Error Info

**BSOD Error**: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

**Conditions for Crash**: Anytime a game is being played. Although this seems to be worse when raytracing is enabled or when playing games that include raytracing.

### Troubleshooting Steps Performed

**Logs**: Nothing of consequence in the event viewer logs. Just the typical "unexpected power down" stuff. No dumps in C:\Windows[\Minidump] due to error writing log during crash as indicated by event in log after crash.

**System Status**: Using HWInfo, checked all temps during gameplay leading up to crash, max temps were:

- CPU: 68c (hotspot, all core avg was 60.8c)
- Chipset: 50c
- GPU: 61c (hotspot, max reported temp was 54.1)
- RAM: 51c

**RAM Tests**:

- Windows Memory Diagnostic: No faults found.
- MemTest86: No faults found.

**Hard drive status**: No issues found. SSD games are installed to is at 97% life remaining, OS NVME drive is at 86% life remaining.

**PSU**: This is the only other potential for a problem that I see. I don't know enough about voltages to know if something is getting under/over-volted, but I do have the voltages logged along with the temps from HWInfo.

### Other Information

I am hesitant to think it's a graphics card issue because I do not get dropped frames, low framerates, graphical artifacting, or anything else that would indicate there is an issue right up until the game crashes. Everything works just fine 100% and then BSOD out of nowhere.

### What I need

Can anyone please help me with further steps I could take towards troubleshooting this issue, or advise if you think warrantying the graphics card is the best course of action at this time?

Comment: Enable mini dumps, get it to crash, then open the dump file with WhoCrashed. It should tell you which driver caused the issue, then you can update that devices drivers. A 1000W PSU is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Mini dumps are enabled but fail due to an error during the crash. Error in event viewer is "Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation."

Comment: Wow, I've not seen that one before. That's properly broken! If the dump file can't be created, then there must be a problem with the drive it's trying to write to. Have you performed a write test with something like SeaTools?

Comment: Yep, tested the hard drives first because that's usually the culprit for these kinds of things. Everything checked out fine. I also updated to the latest bios and chipset drivers for my motherboard in the hopes that it might let the minidump file be created, but no such luck. It did let the BSOD actually stay up, but it was just stuck at 0% for 20 minutes.